# Weierstrass M- test for real valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $x \in [0,\infty)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}-nx}{n^{3}+nx}$.   I want to see whether the series converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$ . Using the M-test we have $\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}|\frac{x^{2}-nx}{n^{3}+nx}|$. After here I am lost. Is it 
$\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}|\frac{x^{2}-nx}{n^{3}+nx}|< \sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}|\frac{1}{n^{3}+nx}|<|\frac{1}{n^{3}}|$ ?????

Comment: Why do you think that $|x^2-nx| < 1$ for all $x \ge 0$?

Comment: Ok, I see.It's not true because when x=2 it does not hold for all n, $|4-2n|<1$ @FlybyNight

Comment: One other question would be: "What do you think that it converges to?"

Comment: to 0 @FlybyNight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the Weirstrass M-test fails.

Recall that for the M-test to show convergence on a sum of functions $a_1(x) + a_2(x) + a_3(x) + \cdots$, we need each of the $|a_i(x)|$ to have suprema, say $s_i$, *and* the sum of those suprema $s_1 + s_2 + s_3 + \cdots$ to converge.

As far as I can tell, all of your summands are unbounded, i.e. there is no supremum.

Let's use polynomial division. First, write

$$\frac{x^2-nx}{n^3+nx} \equiv \frac{x^2-nx+0}{nx+n^3}$$

Here, we are treating $n$ as a constant. If we perform the division, we see that
$$\frac{x^2-nx}{n^3+nx} \equiv \frac{1}{n}x + n-1+\frac{n^2-n^3}{x+n^2}$$

It seems to follow that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2-nx}{n^3+nx} = \infty$$

Hence, none of the terms in your original sum are bounded above on $x \ge 0$.